# how can i get correct Collation by sql query or other way of Sqlserver

Tags: java, sql-server, collation

I can get all collation by below query:

```
SELECT name, description FROM sys.fn_helpcollations();

Albanian_BIN
Albanian_BIN2
Albanian_CI_AI
Albanian_CI_AI_WS
Albanian_CI_AI_KS
Albanian_CI_AI_KS_WS
Albanian_CI_AS
Albanian_CI_AS_WS
Albanian_CI_AS_KS
Albanian_CI_AS_KS_WS
Albanian_CS_AI
Albanian_CS_AI_WS
Albanian_CS_AI_KS
Albanian_CS_AI_KS_WS
Albanian_CS_AS
Albanian_CS_AS_WS
Albanian_CS_AS_KS
Albanian_CS_AS_KS_WS
Albanian_100_BIN
Albanian_100_BIN2
Albanian_100_CI_AI
Albanian_100_CI_AI_WS
Albanian_100_CI_AI_KS
Albanian_100_CI_AI_KS_WS
Albanian_100_CI_AS
Albanian_100_CI_AS_WS
Albanian_100_CI_AS_KS
Albanian_100_CI_AS_KS_WS
Albanian_100_CS_AI
Albanian_100_CS_AI_WS
Albanian_100_CS_AI_KS
Albanian_100_CS_AI_KS_WS
Albanian_100_CS_AS
Albanian_100_CS_AS_WS
Albanian_100_CS_AS_KS
Albanian_100_CS_AS_KS_WS
Albanian_100_CI_AI_SC
Albanian_100_CI_AI_WS_SC
Albanian_100_CI_AI_KS_SC
Albanian_100_CI_AI_KS_WS_SC
Albanian_100_CI_AS_SC
Albanian_100_CI_AS_WS_SC
Albanian_100_CI_AS_KS_SC
Albanian_100_CI_AS_KS_WS_SC
Albanian_100_CS_AI_SC
Albanian_100_CS_AI_WS_SC
Albanian_100_CS_AI_KS_SC
Albanian_100_CS_AI_KS_WS_SC
Albanian_100_CS_AS_SC
Albanian_100_CS_AS_WS_SC
Albanian_100_CS_AS_KS_SC
Albanian_100_CS_AS_KS_WS_SC
Arabic_BIN
Arabic_BIN2
Arabic_CI_AI
Arabic_CI_AI_WS
Arabic_CI_AI_KS
Arabic_CI_AI_KS_WS
Arabic_CI_AS
...
```

i found that there are more than one collation per each locale

when we setup sqlserver, sqlserver can select default collation follow current OS's locale.

so, i also want to know which collation is used by default.

for example, current locale is that:

```
System.out.println(Locale.getDefault().getDisplayCountry());
System.out.println(Locale.getDefault().getDisplayLanguage());
System.out.println(Locale.getDefault().getDisplayName());
System.out.println(Locale.getDefault().getLanguage());
```

output:

```
United States
English
English (United States)
en
```

now, during the sqlserver installation, it will use "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" automatically, how does sqlserver know it, where are the mapping list?

i want to get the default collation by some api or query sql which like sqlserver get the collation when do installation.

assume i just can get the OS locale info, how do i get the related default Collation by java api or windows native api or query db or any way?

Comment: You can use below query to get SQL server collation..

    select SERVERPROPERTY(N'Collation')

Comment: Taken from [MSDN][1]:

SQL Server collation settings depend on the type of installation. In most cases, a computer runs the Windows system locale that matches the language requirements of the user. Therefore, SQL Server Setup automatically detects the Windows system locale and selects the appropriate SQL Server collation. For backward compatibility, the default English-language (US) collation is SQL_Latin1_General*.


  [1]: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144260(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318101(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: when sqlserver get the OS locale, then how does it get the related collation, i want to know this function or procedure

Comment: I think the info provided in link has info

Comment: i find a table which list all mapping relationship, and i also find getLocalInfo function, but i can't find api like getCollation(local)